# ios 7.0 simulator on Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an app on Xcode 5.1.1

I have some labels that display dynamic text. I do not understand their behavior.

I have no problems on ios6.0

on ios7.1 i had to put

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

to remove a white background that covered part of the text

on ios7.0 only part of the text is visible

[image]

how can I download the simulator to ios7.0? in "other simulators" is not present

Answer (score 1):

There is known bug where the UITableViewCell background is set to white when displaying.

A solution is to set the background colour in the  `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: i just used this solution for ios 7.1...but, as u can see in the image, the problem is for ios7.0